# Is there any issue with wiring a GFCI to a switch?

Tags: switch, gfci, cabinets

We have a wire the goes from Breaker > 2 switches.

first switch goes to a recessed lighting above
second switch goes below to an outlet under the sink in a cabinet that controls the garbage disposal, which is the only thing connected to that outlet.

The outlet is currently a standard outlet, and I want to replace it with a Decora GFCI since it's under the sink.

The 2nd switch is going to be connected to a GFCI is that is basically off 99.99999% of the time. The only time anyone turns it on is because they accidently thought it was the overhead recessed lighting switch.

AS FAR AS I KNOW. There are no other lines on the circuit connected to this outlet. I've looked and looked and looked and found nothing else.

Picasso

[image]

Answer (score 5):

### Use a switch-rated deadfront GFCI

I'd replace the existing garbage disposal switch with a switching-rated deadfront GFCI device, such as the Legrand 2087 depicted below.  That way, it's clearly distinct from the switch for the recessed lights, and also less vulnerable to a leak under the sink.

[image: Legrand/P&S 2087 switch-rated deadfront GFCI device]

Comment: This answer wins Stackexchange. Off the wall, simple, code legal, solves the UX problem,  and dead nuts right. Also posted within 10 minutes!

Comment: damnit, THIS is so cool. But I already bought GFCI's from Hubbell. ARG! So basically you put this above the counter, and a normal outlet below the counter?

Comment: @OutdatedComputerTech yes, you are right -- this would go above the counter, with a normal outlet below

Comment: Wow!!  Have never seen one of these.  Cool.

Comment: Actually, with this, you don't even need a receptacle below. The garbage disposal can be *hard wired*, provided it is designed to support that (mine do, I think most do, but check the manufacturer's instructions to be sure).

Comment: @threephaseeel as much as I respect this answer. It doesn't really answer my original question. :(